# HttpWebRequest times out at HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have spent hours trying to figure out this issue and followed the solutions on similar questions but nothing has worked so far. I'm starting to get frustrated as I have ran out of solutions to work with.

I'm trying to upload a file to the server via HttpWebRequest. The connection times out at HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() every time. Reading the questions here, I have seen this is the issue with the connection not being properly disposed. I think I'm closing the connection properly and my reposnse stream is also enclosed in a `using` block as suggested by many here.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest requestToServer = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

// Define a boundary string
string boundaryString = "----";

// Turn off the buffering of data to be written, to prevent
// OutOfMemoryException when sending data
requestToServer.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
// Specify that request is a HTTP post
requestToServer.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
// Specify that the content type is a multipart request
requestToServer.ContentType
    = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
// Turn off keep alive
requestToServer.KeepAlive = false;


ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
string boundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "\r\n";
byte[] boundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(boundaryStringLine);

string lastBoundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "--\r\n";
byte[] lastBoundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(lastBoundaryStringLine);


string fileUrl = file;
// Get the byte array of the string part of the myFile content
// disposition
string myFileContentDisposition = string.Format(
    "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"{0}\"; "
     + "filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
    "myFile", Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), Path.GetExtension(fileUrl));
byte[] myFileContentDispositionBytes =
    ascii.GetBytes(myFileContentDisposition);

var name = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUrl);

// Calculate the total size of the HTTP request
long totalRequestBodySize = boundaryStringLineBytes.Length * 2
    + lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length
    + myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length
    + fileInfo.Length;
// And indicate the value as the HTTP request content length
requestToServer.ContentLength = totalRequestBodySize;


// Write the http request body directly to the server
using (Stream s = requestToServer.GetRequestStream())
{

    // Send the file content disposition over to the server
    s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
    s.Write(myFileContentDispositionBytes, 0,
        myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length);

    // Send the file binaries over to the server, in 1024 bytes chunk
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } // end while

    fileStream.Close();

    // Send the last part of the HTTP request body
    s.Write(lastBoundaryStringLineBytes, 0, lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length);

    string responseString = "";
    WebResponse response = requestToServer.GetResponse();

    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseString;
        }
    }
}
```

The timeout occurs at `using (Stream s = requestToServer.GetRequestStream())`.Everything was working fine before but now it's not. I will greatly appreciate if someone can figure out what's wrong with my code.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here's the full stack trace:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)

06-03 09:15:41.521 D/Mono    ( 3839): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
06-03 09:15:41.521 D/Mono    ( 3839): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
06-03 09:15:41.522 D/Mono    ( 3839): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
06-03 09:15:41.523 D/Mono    ( 3839): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
06-03 09:15:41.523 D/Mono    ( 3839): Probing '__android_log_print'.
06-03 09:15:41.524 D/Mono    ( 3839): Found as '__android_log_print'.
06-03 09:15:41.536 I/MonoDroid( 3839): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-03 09:15:41.537 I/MonoDroid( 3839): System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000c2] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.UploadFile.upload (System.String file, System.String url) [0x000e6] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\UploadFile.cs:115 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.MainActivity+<button_Click>d__0.MoveNext () [0x0003d] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\MainActivity.cs:57 
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-03 09:15:41.538 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.539 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:41.539 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18 
06-03 09:15:41.539 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
06-03 09:15:41.539 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71 
06-03 09:15:41.539 I/MonoDroid( 3839):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:014507e3-fd28-45b0-b68f-cb466da601fa (intptr,intptr)
An unhandled exception occured.

06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839): 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839): Unhandled Exception:
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839): System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000c2] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.UploadFile.upload (System.String file, System.String url) [0x000e6] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\UploadFile.cs:115 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.MainActivity+<button_Click>d__0.MoveNext () [0x0003d] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\MainActivity.cs:57 
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:014507e3-fd28-45b0-b68f-cb466da601fa (intptr,intptr)
06-03 09:15:43.243 E/mono    ( 3839):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:014507e3-fd28-45b0-b68f-cb466da601fa (intptr,intptr)
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000c2] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.UploadFile.upload (System.String file, System.String url) [0x000e6] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\UploadFile.cs:115 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at chunkedUpload.MainActivity+<button_Click>d__0.MoveNext () [0x0003d] in c:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\chunkedUpload\chunkedUpload\MainActivity.cs:57 
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:014507e3-fd28-45b0-b68f-cb466da601fa (intptr,intptr)
06-03 09:15:43.244 E/mono-rt ( 3839):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:014507e3-fd28-45b0-b68f-cb466da601fa (intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: "Everything was working fine before but now it's not."  What changed between the time it was working and now?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code. I was testing something out which didn't work so I restored the changes I made

Comment: Could there be a problem on the server side then?  Are you sure your request is making it to the server?  If you are getting an exception, can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: The request doesn't make it to the server before connection times out. Updated my post for the stack trace.

Comment: Since this is an Android app, do you have the Internet permission in your manifest file?  Are you sure the URL for the server is correct and your device is connected to a network that can access the server?  What happens if you make the same request to the server using something like curl or Postman?

Comment: I have done this before many times and this never happened before. I have my IIS setup for remote request and I have tested the endpoint using fiddler so it all works fine. The problem seems to be with the connection pool, there's a connection left open. I'm not quite sure how it works though.

Comment: Are there other places in your app that are making requests to the same server before this one happens?

Comment: no this is the only place where the request is made